# Regex to extract from string in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a string

```
string = <td class=\"title\"><a href=\"/title/tt0075669/\">Amar Akbar Anthony</a><div class=\"desc_preview\" title=\"10/10&#10;votes 2\"> </div>\n</td>
```

I am using the code

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string,"[A-Z]\\w+")
```

For this I am getting result

```
> str_extract(string,"[A-Z]\\w+")
[1] "Amar"
```

However I want "Amar Akbar Anthony" as my output. How should I change my regex suitably for this?

Comment: Add a space - `"[A-Z][\\w\\s]+"`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your regex does not allow spaces. Add it as `[\\w\\s]`:

```
"[A-Z][\\w\\s]+"
```

Also, if your string is always in the format above, you do not even need the `stringr` library, use a base R `gsub`:

```
s <- "<td class=\"title\"><a href=\"/title/tt0075669/\">Amar Akbar Anthony</a><div class=\"desc_preview\" title=\"10/10&#10;votes 2\"> </div>\n</td>"
trimws(gsub("<[^>]+>","",s))
[1] "Amar Akbar Anthony"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/6FqXEi). The `gsub("<[^>]+>","",s)` will remove all open/close/etc. tags.

Or use the XML parsing library to grab the `a` tag values:

```
> library("XML")
> s <- "<td class=\"title\"><a href=\"/title/tt0075669/\">Amar Akbar Anthony</a><div class=\"desc_preview\" title=\"10/10&#10;votes 2\"> </div>\n</td>"
> parsed_doc = htmlParse(s, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
> res <- getNodeSet(doc = parsed_doc, path = "//a/text()")
> plain_text <- sapply(res, xmlValue)
> plain_text
[1] "Amar Akbar Anthony"
```

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** Whoops! I mis-understood your question. The way I normally extract stuff from between two HTML tags, is to use positive lookbehind on a ">", then read everything until the next "<".

```
string = "<td class=\"title\"><a href=\"/title/tt0075669/\">Amar Akbar Anthony</a><div class=\"desc_preview\" title=\"10/10&#10;votes 2\"> </div>\n</td>"

str_extract(string,"(?<=>)[^<]+")
```

This is a bit fragile. The better answer is you don't use regexes to parse HTML. (`htmlTreeParse()` from the [XML library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) is one approach; the [httr package](https://github.com/hadley/httr) also has a function for this.)

My original answer, to extract all words as a list:

Switch from `str_extract()` to `str_extract_all()`

```
str_extract(string,"[A-Z]\\w+")
[1] "Amar"

str_extract_all(string,"[A-Z]\\w+")
[[1]]
[1] "Amar"    "Akbar"   "Anthony"
```